# How To Display Error Messages With Wufoo API V3?

Tags: json, forms, api, wufoo

I am using the Wufoo API V3 to submit data from a form hosted on my website to my Wufoo account. I followed the example on the [Entries POST API][1] page, and I was able to successfully the data to my account.

I was wondering how I am able to check for error messages, and display the ErrorText for each text input field using PHP?

For example, if someone does not provide their email address in a required email field.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?
function submit() { 
    $ref = curl_init('https://myname.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/xxxxxx/entries.json'); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data')); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, getPostParams()); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ref, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Wufoo.com'); 
    $response = curl_exec($ref);
    echo $response;  
} 

function getPostParams() { 
    return array( 'Field4' => "you@company.com"); 
} 

submit();
?>
```

---

**UPDATE (Nov 12, 2011):**

MinisterOfPower,

Thanks for [the reply and advice][2] about the Wufoo PHP API Wrapper. I am now using the API Wrapper and it rocks. I am having some challenges integrating the code you provided with my form.

For example, if I have a form on index.php (see below) with an email required field. How would I be able to set up the API wrapper to display an error next to the appropriate input field after the form is submitted?

Here's the code for *index.php*:

```
<? require_once('my-wrapper.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label id="email" class="icons" for="Field4">Email</label>
        <input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="text" class="formreg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label id="name" class="icons" for="Field6">Name</label>
        <input id="Field6" name="Field6" type="text" class="formreg"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="saveForm" value="Submit" id="submit" class="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idstamp" name="idstamp" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" />
</form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for *my-wrapper.php*:

```
$wrapper = new WufooApiWrapper('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX', 'mysubdomain','wufoo.com'); 
$postArray = array();
foreach ($this->postValues as $value => $key) {
    $postArray[] = new WufooSubmitField($key, $value);
}

try {
    $result = $wrapper->entryPost('XXXXXX', $postArray);         
    if (!$result->Success) {
        foreach ($result->FieldErrors as $key => $value) {
            echo "Error on $key.  Error Text: $value <br />";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Read the error message.
}
```

---

**UPDATE (Nov 20, 2011):**

I am now able to display the error messages with the help of MinisterofPower's code and the Wufoo API wrapper. I have a couple of follow up questions:

1. I was wondering how I do set up the form below with PHP so that it posts the entries upon pressing the submit button?
2. Is it possible to do this using AJAX so the page does not refresh?

*Here's the code:*

```
<?
// API
require_once('WufooApiExamples.php');

// Wufoo
$wrapper = new WufooApiWrapper('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX', 'mysubdomain','wufoo.com'); 


// Post Entries    
$postArray = array();
foreach ($this->postValues as $key => $value) {
    $postArray[] = new WufooSubmitField($key, $value);
}

try {
    $result = $wrapper->entryPost('xxxxxx', $postArray);
    if (!$result->Success) {  
        foreach ($result->FieldErrors as $key => $value) { 
           $fieldError[$value->ID] = $value->ErrorText;
        } 
    } 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Read the error message.
}

// Add Errors
function addErrors($fieldName, $fieldError, $add){
    if($fieldError[$fieldName] != ''){
        if ($add == 'message') return '<p class="errors">'.$fieldError[$fieldName].'</p>';
        else if ($add == 'class') return 'class ="errors"';
    }
}
?>

<!--Begin Form-->
<div <? echo addErrors('Field4', $fieldError, 'class') ?>>
<label id="profile" class="icons" for="Field4">Email</label>
<input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="text" class="formreg" tabindex="1"/>
<? echo addErrors('Field4', $fieldError, 'message')?>
</div>

<div <? echo addErrors('Field6', $fieldError, 'class') ?>>
<label id="profile" class="icons" for="Field6">Name</label>
<input id="Field6" name="Field6" type="text" class="formreg" tabindex="1"/>
<? echo addErrors('Field6', $fieldError, 'message')?>
</div>
<!--End Form-->
```

Answer (score 2):

The process of retrieving the response is outlined in the [API docs](http://www.wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/entries/post/#response).  Also, the markup for field errors in found the [Dealing With Failure](http://www.wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/entries/post/#fail) section.

Is is worth nothing that Wufoo offers API Wrappers for [PHP](https://github.com/wufoo/Wufoo-PHP-API-Wrapper) and [many other](https://github.com/wufoo) languages.  I highly suggest using one of those since they make the process so much easier.

Using the Wufoo API, you'd search for a Success value of 0 in the response object and then parse the Field Errors node, as shown here:

```
$wrapper = new WufooApiWrapper($this->apiKey, $this->subdomain, 'wufoo.com');
$postArray = array();
foreach ($this->postValues as $value => $key) {
    $postArray[] = new WufooSubmitField($key, $value);
}

try {
    $result = $wrapper->entryPost($this->formHash, $postArray);         
    if (!$result->Success) {
        foreach ($result->FieldErros as $key => $value) {
            echo "Error on $key.  Error Text: $value <br />";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Read the error message.
}
```

A followup question was posted above, so I'll add my answer here.

You asked how to display an error next to the form in question.  You could do this with either javascript or php.  I'll show you the PHP way only.

Using PHP, you could redirect back to the form with a value in the GET param of the URL, enumerating the error fields and messages.  So, for example, you could do this:

```
for($result->FieldErrors as $name => $value) {
    $str.="$name=$value&";
}

if($str) {
    $str = '?errors=true&'.$str;
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$str");
    exit;
}
```

Then, you'd wrap the above code in this if statement to check for error values on postback, like so:

```
if($_GET['errors']) {
    require_once('my-wrapper.php');
else
    //Your HTML HERE
endif
```

After that, add some PHP conditions which append class names to your fields if they contain errors.  For example:

```
<label id="Field4" class="icons <?php if ($_GET['Field4']) echo 'error'; ?>" for="Field4">Email</label>
```

Finally, add some CSS to call out the error fields with a color or other indicator.

The other way to do this is with javascript.

Use the same logic as above, but add the following script to your page (grabbed from [here](http://www.idealog.us/2006/06/javascript_to_p.html) and [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=134282).)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function getQueryVariable(variable) { 
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
  var vars = query.split("&"); 
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) { 
    var pair = vars[i].split("="); 
    if (pair[0] == variable) { 
      return 'error'; 
    } 
  } 
}

function changeClass (elementID, newClass) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);

    element.setAttribute("class", newClass); //For Most Browsers
    element.setAttribute("className", newClass); //For IE; harmless to other browsers.
}

changeClass('Field4', 'error');
</script>
```

Then use this markup instead:

```
   <label id="Field4" class="icons" for="Field4">Email</label>
```

Good luck.

PS: This code was written here in SO, so it will probably contain syntax errors.  But you can get the point...

Comment: MinisterOfPower, I appreciate the prompt reply. I posted a followup question above.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in PHP. I would be incredibly grateful if you could create the example with javascript because I am more familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm still working on the code. I will post an update soon.

Comment: I am having some challenge could redirecting back to the form with a value in the GET param of the URL. Also when I try to test the API Wrapper on it's own, I receive the following error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context..." On a side note, is it possible to check and display errors without refreshing the page with AJAX?

Comment: I posted an update to my original response above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.